# Выполнить консольную команду c аргументами не запуская CMD.EXE в .NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

Каким образом выполнить консольную команду не запуская `cmd` ?

Comment: какую? и почему важно не запустить cmd.exe ?

Comment: например работа с консолью php

Comment: надо запустить cmd.exe чтобы выполнить команду, но само окно сделать скрытым

Comment: Запуск процесса без cmd.exe, как вариант.

Comment: для того чтобы выполнить под виндой CLI PHP команды можно и запустить php.exe с параметрами, так? Или один раз запустить и потом передавать только параметры, или так не выйдет?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Пример со скрытым cmd.exe

```
string cmd = "calc.exe";

var proc = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    UseShellExecute = true,
    WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32",
    FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe",
    Arguments = "/c " + cmd,
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
};

Process.Start(proc);
```